# umask for internal-sftp in Docker container

Tags: docker, sftp, openssh, sshd, umask

I have a rather simple sftp Docker container in which I have the following `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, inspired by so many different sources on the Internet – no claims that it's perfect, but hey, it kind of works.

```
Port 22
Protocol 2

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

PermitRootLogin no

PubkeyAuthentication no
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0002

Match Group sftponly
      ChrootDirectory %h
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
      AllowTcpForwarding no
      X11Forwarding no
```

emphasis on the `Subsystem` line towards the end. It is my understanding that the `-u` option sets the umask for the process, and therefore the users that log into it. Needless to say, my poor user keeps creating files with permissions `644/755` instead of the expected `664/775`.

What am I missing? Is there a capability that my container is missing? Is there something else?

Comment: The `umask` gets set usually also in startup scripts (`~/.bashrc` and so) or in PAM: `pam_umask`. It is possible it gets overwritten by some of these means.

Comment: Startup scripts should not get invoked, as these are `nologin` accounts. I'll look into PAM, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH implements [SFTP version 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol#Version_3), described in
[draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02.txt](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02). Version 3 of the SFTP protocol includes a [command](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-6.9) for the client to set [file attributes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-5) for files on the server. File attributes which can be set includes the file's permissions.

A umask is only applied when a file (or directory, etc) is created. A process can call [chmod()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chmod.html) to change a file attributes, and these calls are *not* subject to a umask.

In other words, despite the umask, the client can set permissions on files to whatever it wants by sending an explicit command to set the permissions.

Comment: And there is no way of disabling it?